# Sort android contacts with custom fields

Tags: android

I have list of contacts with custom fields. I can display them in ListView sorting them
with respect to Displayname, which is not a custom field.

I need to display those contacts ordered/sorted by Company name which is a custom field.

I want to know if it is possible through androids API or should I go with my own manual sorting approach?

Contact tables format for Company field is:
MIMETYPE as INFO_BASIC, and column is Data.DATA4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it yourself, which I think you may, I suggest a [Schwartzian Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).